# How do I keep user logged in securely after retrieving their details via Facebook (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, cookies, authentication

I am planning of using facebook to obtain user information for my web app. I am developing it using Ruby On Rails. Is there a way of keeping my user logged in securely via cookies. Does Rails provide an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically, if you leverage the [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem, and follow [these](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview) directions, you should be up and running pretty quick after setting up your Facebook API key and secret.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Devise gem: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise